# pass string without single quote in spring jdbctemplate

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle

my requirement is to create a insert statement through Spring JDBCTemplate in which I can pass oracle function which execute at database.

e.g - lets assume I have a table employee having column enter_time (datatype is number(20)) and value will be like 20170106213124630560. and insert statement for this table is like -

```
insert into employee (ID, enter_time ) values (1, to_number(to_char(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF')));
```

I have to send enter_time from spring JDBCTemplate code like this -

```
preparedStatement.setString(1,"to_number(to_char(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF'))");
```

But when I used setString() the value comes with single quote and not able to execute the oracle function. also when I tried with

```
 preparedStatement.setLong(1, to_number(to_char(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF')));
```

it give compilation error at 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF'.

Please help me how I can code so that when spring creates a insert statement it can run directly on database.

Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if this kind of thing is possible.  One thing I can think to try is to escape the single quotes, have you tried `"to_number(to_char(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp),\'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF\'))"` or you may need 2 \'s to make it work. `\\'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF\\'`

Comment: I can't do it as a string because when spring will convert it than it will comes with single quote. so in this case 'to_number(to_char(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF'))' will treated as a value and try to insert that string. but my requirement is to execute the value and convert it as 20170106213124630560 before insertion.

Comment: sql query is - insert into TEST_UTC_TIMESTAMP (ID, UTC_TIMESTAMP) values (2, to_number(to_char(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF')));   and value will we inserted after execution of this query is 2 and 20170107143056543257.    the second value is oracle systime upto 6 digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set it as a parameter as there is nothing that you need to set. `systimestamp` is oracle built-in. Try this:

```
String sql = "insert into TEST_UTC_TIMESTAMP (ID, UTC_TIMESTAMP) values (?, to_number(to_char(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp),'YYYYMMDDHH2‌​4MISSFF')))";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, 2);
int n = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Gurv. it will work if I write insert statement directly but I have to follow the parameter approach since it is part of the existing code. Also table has more than 200 column and the value for each column is decided on runtime. so I have to follow parameter approach.

Comment: I don't see why this need to be parameterized. If you *really* have to, you can find this value in java code and set it. systimestamp is part of oracle database, not java

Comment: if i calculate date time value in java. it will never give me the correct time, when the record is enter in database. and in case of multi threaded env, it will misguide also.  thats why i want the actual datetime when it will enter in database.

Comment: That's why I said not to parameterize it.

Comment: Thanks Gurv. your suggestion works for me .. Thanks a lot.